# Magento 2 : Prevent product add to cart on ENTER key press

Tags: magento2, addtocart

If I press enter key on product page **qty** box, the product will add to cart automatically so I want to prevent this on press ENTER key button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added below code inside qty box :

```
onkeydown="return (event.keyCode !== 13);"
```

so my input box :

```
<input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       maxlength="12"
                       value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
```